# Duplicate local variable for naming thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Because I have a thread and in my main program I want to create multiple threads of the same thing and I don't want the same name I tried to create unique names for each thread, e.g `Player_1`, `Player_2`, etc.

The thing is that it throws Duplicate local variable which I know that is because I use the same variable but I don't know how else I can create multiple names for a thread without me writing them. Here is the code.

### Original Question

```
for (int l=0; l < noPlayers; l++){
    String name = P + "" + (l + 1);
    System.out.println(name);
    Player name = new Player(TURN);
}
```

*The `Player` is the thread which extends and `TURN` is just a variable that will be processed.

### Updated Question

```
   import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Referee extends Thread{


}

class Player extends Thread{
    private int TURN;
    public  Player(int TURN) {
        this.TURN = TURN;
       }

    public void run(){

        int win = 0;
        int lose = 0;
        int draw = 0;
        boolean k = true;
        int j = 0; 
    for (j=0;j<=TURN;j++){
             String [] arr = {"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"};
             Random Pick = new Random();

             // randomly selects an index from the arr
             int select = Pick.nextInt(arr.length); 

             // prints out the value at the randomly selected index
             System.out.println("Random String selected: " + arr[select]); 
        }
    }   
}
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int TURN = 0;
        int No_Players = 0;
        int i=0;
        boolean h= true;
        int j=0;
        boolean k = true;


        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock-paper-scissors, this is a tutorial of threads");  
        Scanner number = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Insert the number of players that will play");

        while (h){
            while (!number.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("You didnt insert a number please try again");
            number.next();
            }
            if(number.hasNextInt()){
             j = number.nextInt();
                if(j>1){
                    No_Players = j;
                    h=false;    
                }
                else {  
                    System.out.println("You need a value bigger than 1");
                }
            }
        }   
        System.out.println("Please enter how many turns you want each player to play");

        while (k){
            while (!number.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("You didnt insert a number please try again");
            number.next();
            }
            if(number.hasNextInt()){
             i = number.nextInt();
                if(i>0){
                    TURN = i;
                    k=false;    
                }
                else {  
                    System.out.println("You need a value bigger than 0");
                }
            }
        }   
        System.out.println("This game will have " + No_Players +" players and each one will have " + TURN + " turns");

        Map<String,Thread> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int l = 0; i < No_Players; ++i) {
           String name = "Player_" + i;
           Player player = new Player(TURN);

           player.setName(name);
           map.put(name, player);
           player.start();
        }

    }   
}
```

**Posted the whole code because of some misunderstandings.

Comment: I don't see any multithreading here at all. You've got a _loop_, but that's quite different, and this one will be executed on just a single thread. What are you trying to do? What's supposed to happen when you instantiate a Player at the end of the loop, and then never use it?

Comment: The variable of type String as well as the variable of type Player is named `Name`. Change one of them

Comment: should i post the whole code or change the tags ... i am new here

Comment: OT: variable names should not start with an uppercase letter  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: After the most recent edit to fix the case of the variable names, there is _still_ a duplicate variable `name`, declared as `String name` and `Player name`. I would suggest the latter should be `Player player = new Player(TURN);`.

Comment: of course there is still a duplicate variable, thats what the question is all about .) @KevinO

Comment: @eckes. My apologies. You are correct about the question and what should be there for the code to match. The case changing without the removal of the duplicate name caught me off guard.

Comment: @KevinO yes - exepected - ... actually I added a comment to explain it, not sure where it is gone, so my bad.

Comment: You should implement Runnable, not extend Thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Player implements Runnable.

```
Map<String,Thread> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
   String name = "Player_" + i;
   Player player = new Player(TURN);
   Thread t = new Thread(player):
   t.setName(name);
   map.put(name, t);
   t.start();
}
```

You can then retrieve the thread by the player name. You can also add a thread group if desired.

Based upon a comment that Player extends Thread (**edit**: fixed the Map definition to use Player rather than Thread).

```
Map<String,Player> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
   String name = "Player_" + i;
   Player player = new Player(TURN);

   player.setName(name);
   map.put(name, player);
   // thread may need to be started elsewhere depending upon the requirement
   player.start();
}
```

Elsewhere to get the particular Player, just do:

```
Player p = map.get(playerName);
```

Based upon a comment, here is working example that show Player, extending Thread, using the Map suggested above, and displaying the players using the `.getName()` method on a Player object.

```
public class TestPlayer
{

public TestPlayer()
{
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numPlayers = 5;

    Map<String,Player> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
       String name = "Player_" + i;
       Player player = new Player(0);

       player.setName(name);
       map.put(name, player);
       // thread may need to be started elsewhere depending upon the requirement
       player.start();
    }

    for (Player p : map.values()) {
        System.out.println("Found player : " + p.getName());
    }


}


static class Player extends Thread
{
    private int turn;

    public Player(int turn)
    {
        this.turn = turn;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Running player " + 
                Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                " turn " + this.turn);
    }
}
```

}

Output:
Running player Player_1 turn 0
Running player Player_3 turn 0
Running player Player_0 turn 0
Running player Player_2 turn 0
Running player Player_4 turn 0
Found player : Player_3
Found player : Player_2
Found player : Player_4
Found player : Player_1
Found player : Player_0

Comment: it extends thread but thanks anyway i think mapping will help too

Comment: @AlexMetsis, if Player extends thread, then you just need to place the Player object in the Map, and not create a new thread based on it.

Comment: @AlexMetsis, for the map.put(), yes. I made an edit assuming Player extends Thread (though I forgot to update the Map definition, will fix).

Comment: You can also implement a constructor for  `Player` which sets the player and thread name `Map<String,Player> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
   String name = "Player_" + i;
   Player player = new Player(name, TURN);
   map.put(name, player);
}`

Comment: what about when i want the name of the thread to be printed out, what command should i put ?

Comment: @eckes, indeed a good point. It is frequently unclear to me how deep into various suggestions to descend. As you noted, setting the name on the Player object would be a good idea, and then I would override the `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` methods of Player, and retrieve via the equality check. I would also not extend Thread but Runnable, and probably use the Executor system.

Comment: @AlexMetsis, because Player extends thread, we set the name of the Thread object, so one can use `player.getName()`, which returns the name of the thread. One nice "feature" here is that in a debugger, the threads will be named the name of the player, making it a bit easier to traverse.

Comment: I used the getName() and when i wanted to print it, it wouldn't appear anything.

Comment: @AlexMetsis, the getName() (unless overridden) from the Thread class (which is what Player extends) should give you the text you set in the setName on the player object. Every thread has a name, so I'm not sure how you would get nothing. Can you edit your question with the updated code?

Comment: Just to echo the concerns, extending Thread in a business/domain object is very ugly. `getName()` is a good example for the conflict to expect. Besides it totally does not fit in any `Executor`-like framework

Comment: i will post all the code but is not like proper finished

Comment: i hope now you can get a better idea

Comment: @AlexMetsis, I looked at the posted code, but I do not see where you called the player.getName(). In all likelihood, I made a mistake by suggesting the question be edited rather than starting a new question. This question needs the original problem put back, and the code where you attempted to print the name needs to be provided. Again, I think separate question. The particulars of the duplicate name problem I think are resolved, and you should probably accept an answer and open a new question.

Comment: oh that i just deleted it because it wasnt working so i didnt put it in. 
             String P= player.getName();
      System.out.println("Name :" + P);
i putted this after the player.start();